# TPH Discriminator not on base class / table

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, tph

I'm having an issue with discriminators in TPH inheritance with Entity Framework v6.1.1

I would expect that the discriminator should fall on the table that is representative of the *base* class. However, it appears EF is trying to map the discriminator column to the table mapped to the *derived* class

E.g.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Staff : Person
{
    public decimal? Salary { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
        : base("MyConnectionString") {}

    public virtual IDbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .Map(x => x.ToTable("Person"))
            .Map<Staff>(x => x.ToTable("Staff").Requires("PersonTypeId").HasValue(1));
    }
}
```

I am also using an existing schema too - i.e:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    PersonTypeId INT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Staff 
(
    Id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Person(Id),
    Salary DECIMAL NULL
)
GO
```

However, when I try to add a new Staff, I encounter the following exception:

> 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PersonTypeId', table 'MyDb.dbo.Person'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated'

It appears that it is trying to insert the discriminator (incorrectly) to the derived table. Hope someone can help.

Comment: sounds weird to use several tables for a TablePerHierarchy <=> one table. Are you sure you're no trying TPT and in this cas there is no need for discriminator.

Comment: Sorry - just used this as an example. Imagine if you will that it will span across more types (eg: Student)

Comment: same remarks for any number of types: in TPH you use only one table for the whole hierarchy. [http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph]

Comment: Ah - right you are - I appear to have my wires crossed around TPT / TPH. No need for a discriminator. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that I've mis-understood the TPH setup for Entity Framework.

In my case, I'm wanting to map derived types to separate tables, which is an example of Table per Type - http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt

Discriminators are redundant in this context.